# Tree graph intuition + mathematical notation

Tags: graph-theory, notation

> Let $T$ be a tree with at least two vertices. Consider a path of maximal length in $T$. Prove that the start and end point of this path have degree 1

**by contradiction** : If we let the start and end point of this path NOT have degree 1, there would be another vertex after the end/beginning making the path longer, so it can only be maximal if it is an end point.

Is this a good intuition for this? I wouldnt even know where to start with the mathematical notation..

Comment: What sort of notation are you looking for? Writing in plain and *very* clear words is much better.

Comment: It feels incomplete a lot of the time. My professor told me the same exact thing ot use CLEAR wording and be very precise.

Comment: Trust me, the time for using "cool math symbols" will come. Stick to clear words, you'll understand better, and whoever grades your work will understand better.

Comment: Alright, ill do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is good, but it is incomplete. What if the other vertex is actually on the path?
This is how I would write it (without using almost any notation):

Let $w$ be any vertex of $T$ and $P$ be a path of maximal length in T going through $w$. [Note that $P$ exists as T is connected and has at least two vertices, so the set of all paths going though $w$ is not empty and finite (I am assuming $T$ itself is finite)].

Now let $a$ be the starting point of $P$. I show that the only vertex adjacent to $a$ in $T$ is the vertex adjacent to $a$ on the path $P$ (then this would mean that $a$ has degree 1). Suppose for a contradiction there is a **different** vertex, say $b$, adjacent to $a$. If $b$ is not on $P$, then we can extend $P$ to include $b$, contradicting the maximality of $P$. If $b$ is on $P$, then the path from $a$ to $b$ in $P$ and the edge from $a$ to $b$ would form a cycle, contradicting that $T$ is acyclic. So $a$ has degree 1. Similarly for the endpoint.